# The default Kafka partitioner create hash key collision

Tags: hash, apache-kafka, key, partitioner

I have a topic with 10 partitions, and I have generate events with `A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I` 9 different keys.

I've observed messages doing this:

```
Partition 0- (Message1, Key E), (Message2, Key I)
Partition 1- (Message3, Key F) 
. 
. 
Partition7-(Message4, Key A), (Message5, Key A)
Partition8- Empty 
Partition9- Empty
```

There are 2 messages with different keys in the same partition and there are empty partitions as well.

Is the default [partitioner](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0fe8a448c36c1082ecff0c4ac2757fd7a5841f99/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/DefaultPartitioner.java#L69) of Kafka creating collisions?

I am producing from one stream which is balanced to two default rest [producers](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest/blob/5.2.1-post/kafka-rest/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafkarest/NoSchemaRestProducer.java).

This is what I was expecting:

```
 Partition 0- (Message1, Key E)
 Partition 1- (Message3, Key F) 
 . 
 . 
 Partition7-(Message4, Key A), (Message5, Key A)
 Partition8-(Message2, Key I) 
 Partition9- Empty
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kafka's DefaultPartitioner uses a [murmur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash) hash algorithm at the producer client side to assign a partition to each message. There is no guarantee that for 10 partitions and single digit number of keys, they will be uniformly distributed. Calculation of partition for each message is independent of each other and the probability of collision is a mathematical interest.

**EDIT:**

It is very unlikely that murmur hash algorithm results in a collision. Partitions in Kafka topic is fixed - it cannot grow unlike bucket size in java HashMap implementation. So partition algorithm uses a formula which calculates modulo of number of partitions. Exact formula is `Utils.toPositive(Utils.murmur2(keyBytes)) % numPartitions;`

Now you can see that two different keys can indeed result in same partition number if `hash mod number of partitions` results in same value.

For a large number of random key set, keys will be uniformly distributed across all partitions.

If you want ordering, then you must use a partition key..in which case your worries surrounding collisions and empty partitions have little practical consequences (well, for a large set of random keys, they will be ok). **If you assumed that Kafka would centrally make sure that empty partitions are filled first before a key is routed to an already filled partition, that is not how things work**

Comment: what is the purpose of having a hash that create collision? Any guide in order to choose the keys for not make them collide ?

Comment: @Dipperman, By definition hash should create collision (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)

Comment: @wardziniak I know that hash by definition, can create collision, but i can not understand why do we need collision in Kafka? Not having collision would distribute uniformly.

Comment: If you want to distribute uniformly, leave out the key and the default partitioner will partition using round-robin

Comment: in that case i will have uniformly but disorderly. I need ordering the events regarding its key

Answer (score 1):

Yes the default partitioner is going to create collisions, and it will happen at the latest when you have one more key than you have partitions. See the answer of @senseiwu which explains nicely what happens.
If you have a finite set of keys and want to distribute them over the same number of partitions you must implement your own partitioner.